# Writing the following with an Arrow function

Tags: javascript

I have the following to run that for each array index, it will return the sum of the values at that index. For example:

```js
function unnest(elem) {
    if (!Array.isArray(elem)) {
        return elem;
    } else {
        return elem.flatMap(e => unnest(e));
    }
}

let n = [1,[2,3], [4,[5,6]], 7];
let nx = new Array(n.length);
for (let [idx, elem] of Object.entries(n)) {
    if (Array.isArray(elem)) {
        // const flatMapR = e => Array.isArray(e) ? flatMapR(e) : e;
        let flatArr = unnest(elem);
        let sum = flatArr.reduce((x,y) => x+y);
        nx[idx] = sum;
    } else {
        nx[idx] = elem;
    }
}
console.log(nx);
// [ 1, 5, 15, 7 ]
```

Is there a way to replace the `unnest` function with an arrow function, such as I'm trying to do in the commented code above? If I uncomment that it gives me a recursion error, so I'm guessing maybe an arrow function cannot refer to itself.

Comment: It totally can refer to itself - that's why it recurses. It's just that you never reach a base case, since `flatMapR` is calling itself with exactly the same argument value again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's easy enough to replace that with a single-statement arrow function, and then `map` a `sum` over the results of mapping it to our values.  Just use a conditional expression (ternary).  I'm assuming that this is what you meant, as it's trivial to replace your original function declaration (`function unnest(elem) { ... }`) with the equivalent arrow (`const unnest = (elem) => {...}`).  This is entirely mechanical, with only a minor tweak for `async` functions.  It's not available for generator functions, though, or for methods inside class declarations.

It might look like this:

```js
const unnest = (elem) => Array .isArray (elem) ? elem .flatMap (unnest) : elem
const sum = (ns) => Array .isArray (ns) ? ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0) : ns

const n = [1, [2, 3], [4, [5, 6]], 7]

console .log (n .map (unnest))
console .log (n .map (unnest) .map (sum))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

However, that requires an odd implementation of `sum`.  I would rather flatten the outer list into an array of (flat) arrays, and then apply a more normal `sum` to each, like this:

```js
const unnest = (elem) => Array .isArray (elem) ? elem .flatMap (unnest) : [elem]
const sum = (ns) => ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0) 

const n = [1, [2, 3], [4, [5, 6]], 7]

console .log (n .map (unnest))
console .log (n .map (unnest) .map (sum))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The only difference in the `unnest` functions is in how they handle a scalar value.  The first one returns it as is, the second one wraps it in an array.  I find this more consistent data structure much easier to work with.

Comment: thanks for this. Is `elem .flatMap (unnest)` the same as doing `elem.flatMap(e => unnest(e))` ?

Comment: JS has higher-order functions; they are just values that you can assign, pass, and return like any other.  So these are almost identical, but with a twist.  If `unnest` took a second parameter -- even an optional one that we defaulted -- it would be filled with the second argument that [`flatmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#parameters) supplies, the `index`.  Similarly a third one would get the full `array` argument.  Since `unnest` is unary, and a pure function (not an object method), it's the same thing.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can do this. It's almost unreadable, but here would be the faithful conversion of the function to the arrow expression:

```js
let n = [1,[2,3], [4,[5,6]], 7];
let nx = new Array(n.length);
for (let [idx, elem] of Object.entries(n)) {
    if (Array.isArray(elem)) {
        const flatMapR = elem => !Array.isArray(elem) ? elem : elem.flatMap(e => flatMapR(e));
        let flatArr = flatMapR(elem);
        let sum = flatArr.reduce((x,y) => x+y);
        nx[idx] = sum;
    } else {
        nx[idx] = elem;
    }
}
console.log(nx);
// [ 1, 5, 15, 7 ]
```

Comment: Why not name it `unnest`, move it outside of the `for` loop, and put the conditional across multiple lines - just like the original? Much more readable - just like the original! This has nothing to do with arrow functions.